# Регулярное выражение для идентификатора на js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
var regex=new RegExp("^[_a-zA-Z]\w*&");
if(regex.test('_hello'))
alert('Yes');
else alert('No');
```

Проблема в том, что данный (и другие) идентификаторы не проходят проверку. Как изменить данную регулярку? Строка должна целиком соответствовать шаблону

Comment: А как что то не содержащее `&` пройдет проверку регуляркой, подразумевающей наличие `&`

Comment: @Mike, если вы считаете, что проблема в опечатке пометьте вопрос на закрытие по этой причине

Comment: @Mike, Глаз замылился. Но даже при исправленной опечатке не работает

Comment: а вот так работает `if(/^[_a-zA-Z]\w*$/.test('_hello'))`

Comment: подозреваю дело в экранировании `\\`

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо!

Comment: @PashaPash, не думаю что здесь только в опечатке дело, экранирование символа - вполне себе конкретная проблема, а не опечатка

Answer (score 2):

Помимо опечатки: `&` => `$`

В конструктор передается строка

```
var regex=new RegExp("^[_a-zA-Z]\w*&");
```

и так как это простая строка необходимо экранировать символ `"\"`

```
var regex=new RegExp("^[_a-zA-Z]\\w*$");
```

либо использовать литерал регулярного выражения

```
if(/^[_a-zA-Z]\w*$/.test('_hello'))
```

Comment: А еще идентификатор в JS может начинаться с `$` ЕМНИП.

Comment: @andy.37 ну тут смотря что считать идентификатором

Comment: @andy.37 хотя если вот это [определение](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Identifier) то да

Comment: если уж на то пошло, то и символы Юникода допустимы в идентификаторах, не только a-zA-Z

Comment: @andy.37, в данном случае _a-zA-Z_ это только с чего может начинаться идентификатор, а не только из чего может состоять

Comment: Начинаться с не ASCII тоже может)))